# ng-repeat code getting commented out when viewed from browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I see during load that the scope element `$scope.docDetails`  has the necessary data.

In the view when I use the ng-repeat to print info, I see that it is not displayed in browser.

```
<body ng-controller="documentUploadController" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" filters="queueLimit, customFilter">
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="row in documentUploadController.docDetails">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{row.DocumentTypeName}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 elementwrap"><a href="#" ng-click="documentUploadController.downloadDocument(row)">{{row.FileName}}</a> </div>
 ..
        </div>
    </div>
```

WHen i view the HTML ,i see the ng-repeat code being commented out

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: could you please show the controller or the data (docDetails) your using

Comment: When you add simple text into div before `{{` is it visible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, your ng-repeat variable is `$scope.docDetails`

Since $scope already equals the controller, remove the controller reference in `ng-repeat`  like  `<div ng-repeat="row in docDetails">`

```
<body ng-controller="documentUploadController" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" filters="queueLimit, customFilter">
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="row in docDetails">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{row.DocumentTypeName}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 elementwrap"><a href="#" ng-click="documentUploadController.downloadDocument(row)">{{row.FileName}}</a> </div>
 ..
        </div>
    </div>
```